# Intersection of streets on a map

Tags: geography

I have a street route on a map and I want to find the coordinates of the intersection of the streets that come off of it.

For example, [image]

the red path is the route taken, I want to find the coordinates of all the streets coming from this.

I know I can hover over the map and get co ordinates of the intersection but, is there a way to not do this manually?

Thanks!